# Asp.net MVC ReportViewer ,IIS 7 issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, report-viewer2010

I use asp.net mvc 2, added webform with reportviewer controls.

The web.config file looks

```
     <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting`enter code here`.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b0`enter code here`3f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

```
    <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />

  <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <add name="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

IIS is configured as a link

http://otkfounder.blogspot.com/2007/11/solving-reportviewer-rendering-issue-on.html

But I still have the error

### Report Viewer Configuration Error

The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file.  Add <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /> to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or add <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /> to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what we have - it should support both IIS 6 and IIS7+
I think you've got a reference to v9 of Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd (Reporting Services 2005)

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
                                <etc />
            <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </assemblies>
                        <!-- Edit Unsure as to whether this is needed, or should be Microsoft.ReportViewer.Webforms. Was upgraded from RDLC v9 -->
        <buildProviders>
            <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </buildProviders>
    </compilation>


    <!-- NB : The below is for earlier IIS -->
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="true"/>
    </httpHandlers>

</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <!-- NB : The below is for IIS 6+ W2008 Server / Vista -->
    <handlers>
        <add name="Reserved-ReportViewerWebControl-axd" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

**Edit** : Note that as of v10 the RdlBuildProvider is now in Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms not in Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common

Comment: Error 8 Could not load type 'Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider' from assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Comment: Looks like the buildprovider is either no longer needed (comment it out), or is now in WebForms.dll - see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/f2a6d0a8-6c6f-467b-a1e2-210d7b0c42ec. Note that if you have reports written in older versions there may be issues upgrading them.

Comment: I dont know what to do does not work I tried it all alive.
Please help mija I'll go crazy

Comment: @IvanIvan, how did you solve the problem?  Was it StuartLC's post alone?  I am hosting with Arvixe and have this problem, cannot figure it out.  Thanks.